# Can every ADSL router handle high data transfer rates?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, file-sharing, modem

I had this Nokia Siemens ADSL wireless router (with 4 Ethernet ports). I used it as a router to transfer files over WiFi between two PCs and as an internet gateway.

It worked okay for some days (although heating badly while transferring files), and files were transferring at about 8~10 MB/s. Then it failed and started to reboot every time when data rate exceeded 90 KB/s (rough estimate). That was enough to overheat it.

The repairmen say it's gone completely, so I'm looking for a new one (D-Link most probably). But I don't want the new modem-router to behave the same way.

Can all routers handle this kind of transfer or is there something I should look at when deciding to buy one?

Comment: can I get a router modem that supports that high data rates?

Comment: please note I mean 10MBps not 10Mbps...and that too over wifi i think you know the difference

Comment: Oh, I see now. Yes, that's a difference. I think I misunderstood how you were using the router exactly.

Comment: A good, well made modem/router should not have such issues - even crappy modems just creak, rather than dropping dead.

Answer (score 2):

> Can all routers handle this kind of transfer or is there something I
>   should look at when deciding to buy one?

What you had was a modem not a router. Your modem was also a router, not all modems are built the same, and have different features.  Figure out what you want and shop around.  We don't do product suggestions on this website.

Answer (score 2):

Routers don't break down when having to deal with high data rates unless they're already broken, but the maximum transfer speed is limited. The router and host will negotiate a connection speed depending on the quality of the medium and the capabilities of either network card. The maximum speed for a router's WAN and LAN ports should appear prominently in its specifications.

A router might still crash under heavy load, often because the number of connections exceeds the amount the router can keep track of, or due to overheating, but even the cheapest models require some serious effort to fail. It's very uncommon under ordinary circumstances.